# Collecting identifying information about users filling in a Google Docs forms

Tags: google-drive, google-forms

How can I get Google Docs to register IDs of people taking a survey generated from by the form?

I have a database of users and I'd like them to take a survey and also have the form link with their ID so I know which of my users completed the form.

Is it also possible to style a Google Docs form or do I have to stick with one of the few styles provided by Google?

Is all of this possible with Google Docs?

<sub>If not, I may look into SurveyMonkey if it provides these features.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only seem to have some bad news for you.

1. It is not possible to customize Google Docs Forms in another way than using the provided themes. ([See Google employee AnaLikesLattes' answer](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Docs/thread?tid=0dadae883fe8df37&hl=en))
2. It is not possible to enforce one-submission-per-person but you could maybe use required fields asking for first/last name or email. ([Google Docs Help discussion](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Docs/thread?tid=6d2e1ec9e33a3301&hl=en))

I'm not sure about SurveyMonkey (haven't used it) but for more advanced surveys I'd suggest using [SurveyGizmo](http://www.surveygizmo.com/). They offer a free account with 250 responses per month. Comparison of their plan features [here](http://www.surveygizmo.com/survey-features/).